# SharePoint 2013 calendar switch day/week/month view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

as you know, SharePoint Calendar does enable you to switch the calendar view from, for example, from "week" to "month". the three icons are hidden on the ribbon unless you mouse over the calendar. it is not really Intuitive, and I would like to have three buttons or icons on the calendar, so that, users will be able to switch the "day/week/month" view by clicking on it. can you please give me a clue?

Answer (score 0):

an alternative is to create a "week" and/or "day" view and add an icon to link to each of the view.